# Windows 7 Batch Script - "Access Denied" error when using FTP

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I wrote a batch script. I am on WINDOWS 7 and try to ftp file, which are on Linux

```
open MYIP     
MYUSER      
MYPASSWORD      
hash     
cd /home/mktftp/upload/coverimages      
asc     
get DONE.SVRIMG.14102014        
quit      
exit /b
```

and get output below:

```
ftp> Connected to 10.160.2.52.    

open 10.160.2.52     
220 10.160.2.52 FTP server ready    
User (10.160.2.52:(none)):     
331 Password required for user    

530 Access was denied.
```

I don't understand, why it is not working.

Comment: may be you are giving wrong password?

Comment: The password is OK. I tried it manually, it works

Comment: Maybe you don't have permission to read the file `DONE.SVRIMG.14102014`. For security reasons, most tftp server implementations disallow read on uploaded files. Ask your Linux Admin to grant you read permission on that file.

Comment: Before the get line, try a simple couple of commands like pwd and ls to see that you're where you think you are and that the file is there.  I've seen "access denied" when the file wasn't there, although of course it's the wrong response.  Otherwise agree with @alvits that it's a permissions thing you need to resolve elsewhere.

Comment: Something seems strange in what you're doing. You have an `exit /b` which is for a bat file, but the rest should be passed to ftp. Are you storing everything from `open...` to `quit` in a text file, which you then call: `ftp -s:filename`?